# How can I connect from a local Kubernetes to a DB on my local machine

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I'm using **Docker Desktop for mac** for **Kubernetes** in local desktop. I'm trying to connect to DB installed on my local machine within a pod but can't figure what should be the host address. How can I relate to the address of my machine within a pod?

Please note that I can't use the ip of my machine since the db port is blocked in my network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From docker 18.03 onwards, you can use special DNS name`host.docker.internal` which resolves to the internal address used by host.

Please look at the official docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible) for more information on this.

If you're on earlier version than docker 18.03, you need to use the experimental DNS name `docker.for.mac.localhost` to resolve to the local host.

Hope this helps.